# How to execfile file with parameters Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I tried to to that like:

```
execfile('c:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump -h localhost -u ' + username + ' -p' + password + ' ' + database + ' > ' + projectname + '.sql');
```

Then I see an error:

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   'c:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump -h localhost -u root -p pr > pr.sql'

What I do wrong?

I trie to write output to file like:

```
output = subprocess.check_output([r'c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump', '-h', 'localhost', '-u', username, '--password=', database], stdout=open(projectname + '.sql','w'))
```

It does not work

Comment: Are you on Windows ?

Comment: What does it say if you just paste the full command into the terminal and cut out python? It's seems like its a bad path to one of the files and not a python issue.

Comment: Yes under Windows

Comment: How to write output in file? I tried, see question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[execfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile) doesn't take a whole command, but the name of the file to execute as the first argument. Moreover it's a way of calling other Python program, not a generic program - like `mysqldump`.

I suggest you use [`subprocess.call` instead](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module), e.g.

```
subprocess.call(['c:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump', '-h', 'localhost', '-u', username, '-p' + password, database])
```

And then you need to take care of the redirection (typically done by your shell if you run it manually), so the full solution would be:

```
f = open(projectname+".sql", "w")
subprocess.call(['c:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump', '-h', 'localhost', '-u', username, '-p' + password, database], stdout=f)
```

Comment: You missed parameter here `password, database])`.

Comment: @OPV, not sure I get your comment. `-pyoursecret` is a single parameter (no spaces within). As opposed to `-h`, `localhost`which are two parameters. 
I haven't checked what `mysqldump` takes, but following your attempt.

Comment: Man, where is remaining part of command I mean file in which I put data? Like `> db_backup.sql`

Comment: @OPV - saving the output to `.sql` file is described in the last paragraph of my answer (referred to as 'redirection').

Answer (score 2):

`execfile` is designed to run python files only (the name is misleading).

Plus it has been removed from Python 3...

For your issue, just use `subprocess.check_output`, splitting the arguments properly so quoting is handled automatically (never compose your command line by yourself). Here the `-p` option must have the password without spaces (that's a command specificity), or use `--password` which is clearer

```
output = subprocess.check_output([r'c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump', '-h', 'localhost', '-u', username, '--password', password, database])
```

Note: it seems that your password is blank (empty string), in that case, just use `--password=` like explained [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41070/how-do-i-connect-to-a-database-with-a-blank-password-using-a-shell-script)

```
output = subprocess.check_output([r'c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump', '-h', 'localhost', '-u', username, '--password=', database])
```

now the output of your command is in `output` (if the command succeeds), you can write it into a file (well, in your case, it's true that you'be be better off with `check_call` and `stdout=file_handle` because you seem to need the `.sql` file, not only the buffer) anyway:

```
with open("file.sql","w") as f:
   f.write(output)
```

Comment: Where do you put parameter `database`?

Comment: `database` is the last parameter of the command, right after `password`. It's there all right.

Comment: For what there is `output`?

Comment: `output` is the contents of the sql file as python string. Sometimes creating a file isn't needed when you want to process the output from python (saves the reading of the file). Doesn't seem to be your case, though.

Comment: When I execute this `subprocess.call(['c:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump', '-h', 'localhost', '-u', username, '-p' + password, database])` it requires to enter a password in console. How to avoid that?

Comment: "If you omit the password value following the --password or -p option on the command line, mysqldump prompts for one." Are you sure `-p` is collated to the password without spaces?

Comment: It  still waits to enetr password

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158815/discussion-between-opv-and-jean-francois-fabre).

Comment: Man, where is remaining part of command I mean file in which I put data? Like > db_backup.sql